# ASP.NET MVC RemoteAttribute: No url for remote validation could be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-validation

How to configure RemoveAttribute to work with routes like this one?

```
 context.MapExtendedRoute("ValidateSomething",
                                 "some-where/validate/{propName}",
                                 new { Controller = "SomeWhere", Action = "ValidateSomeRouteKey" });
```

When I pass above route name to RemoteAttribute constructor, an `InvalidOperationException` occurs. But works just like a charm when there is no `propName` in route definitions and parameter passed as querystring.

Thanks in advance;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the {propname} parameter to your route, so that you can access it in your controller. In the example below I have made it optional.

```
context.MapExtendedRoute("ValidateSomething",
                             "some-where/validate/{propName}",
                             new { Controller = "SomeWhere", Action = "ValidateSomeRouteKey", propName = UrlParamter.Optional });
```

Comment: No, I have tested this before asking ;)

Comment: Huh, how to tell to RemoteAttribute to do this?